# Python Sockets - Sending Python files

Tags: python, sockets

I'm doing some raspberry pi development, mainly using the programming language Python. **I'm not looking for any coding examples, just advice and possibly tutorials.**

I spend most of my time developing on my laptop, and, when I want to push code to the raspberry Pi for testing, or release it means I have to either ssh through terminal, or, physically code on the Pi.

I'm looking to create a Socket class that will allow me to run the server (on the pi) as well as the the client (on my laptop) which, when I have finished writing the particular script, I can send it over to the Pi which can then execute/run the script, or, interpret the script depending on the actions I give it. Now, I know that I could possibly send each line of code to the pi and have it save as a .py file, however, is it possible to send some kind of /binary/ file over to the Pi and have a two-way type key to make sure that everything was received ok?

Also, is this the right way to go about deploying code/applications to the device?

Comment: You definitely could do this.  Transferring the files this way potentially exposes a security risk, but that's an entirely different question than whether or not it's possible.  And yes, binary files can be transferred via sockets.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Don't want to sound really stupid, but, could you possibly identify some of the security risks? Could I avoid such security risks by allowing specific communication from IP's and make sure they are on my network in order to receive files?

Comment: I'm no security guru - the risks involved in allowing a program to receive (possibly pre-compiled) executable code over a listening socket, and then execute it, are numerous, and would probably be better posed as a question over at http://superuser.com/.  Authentication and check-sums are probably minimums before letting that happen, and host-based or hardware-id based filtering isn't a bad idea either, but a comment is too brief to be exhaustive.

Comment: Have a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/) which aims to aid deployment of scripts with the help of ssh.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:
Yes, you can send binary files over socket. It's done the same way you'd send a text file: Open file, read, send, save. Only difference is that instead of opening the file in text mode, you have to open it in binary mode. [More information here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open)

To check it was sent right, you could send an [md5sum (Or any other *sum)](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/hashlib.html) along with the file to check it.

Personally, I think the right way to go about deploying code to the device is to use SFTP and SSH, since the connections require authentication and are much more secure than a simple socket in python.